# How to filter Spark sql by nested array field (array within array)?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

My spark Dataframe schema

```
|-- goods: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- brand_id: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- product_id: string (nullable = true)
```

I'm able to filter the Dataframe by product_id

```
select * from goodsInfo where array_contains(goods.product_id, 'f31ee3f8-9ba2-49cb-86e2-ceb44e34efd9')
```

But I'm unable to filter by brand_id which is an array within array..

I get the error when I try

```
select * from goodsInfo where array_contains(goods.brand_id, '45c060b9-3645-49ad-86eb-65f3cd4e9081')
```

Error:

```
function array_contains should have been array followed by a value with same element type, but it's [array<array<string>>, string].; line 1 pos 45;
```

Can someone please help ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you please add some sample data and output you are looking for. This will help to understand your requirement better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One more altervative approach, which is not there in the other answers-

> Code is self-explanatory

```scala
    val data=
      """
        |{
        |   "goods": [{
        |       "brand_id": ["brand1", "brand2", "brand3"],
        |       "product_id": "product1"
        |   }]
        |}
      """.stripMargin
    val df = spark.read.json(Seq(data).toDS())
    df.show(false)
    df.printSchema()
    df.createOrReplaceTempView("goodsInfo")

    /**
      * +--------------------------------------+
      * |goods                                 |
      * +--------------------------------------+
      * |[[[brand1, brand2, brand3], product1]]|
      * +--------------------------------------+
      *
      * root
      * |-- goods: array (nullable = true)
      * |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
      * |    |    |-- brand_id: array (nullable = true)
      * |    |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
      * |    |    |-- product_id: string (nullable = true)
      */

    // filter Dataframe by product_id
    spark.sql("select * from goodsInfo where array_contains(goods.product_id, 'product1')").show(false)

    /**
      * +--------------------------------------+
      * |goods                                 |
      * +--------------------------------------+
      * |[[[brand1, brand2, brand3], product1]]|
      * +--------------------------------------+
      */
    // filter Dataframe by brand_id which is an array within array..
    // positive case
    spark.sql("select * from goodsInfo where array_contains(flatten(goods.brand_id), 'brand3')")
      .show(false)

    /**
      * +--------------------------------------+
      * |goods                                 |
      * +--------------------------------------+
      * |[[[brand1, brand2, brand3], product1]]|
      * +--------------------------------------+
      */
    // negative case
    spark.sql("select * from goodsInfo where array_contains(flatten(goods.brand_id), 'brand4')")
      .show(false)

    /**
      * +-----+
      * |goods|
      * +-----+
      * +-----+
      */
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Someshwar for the answer.. :)
If it were one or more level (3+ levels) deep, for ex: goods -> locations -> brands then what would be the best approach ? explode ?

Comment: may be `array_contains(flatten(flatten())` :)

Answer (score 1):

I have created a sample DataFrame and exploded the array column and then filter the records. PFB sample code for the same.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val jsonData = """{
 "id": "0001",
 "batters":
  {
   "batter":
    [
      1001,
      1002,
      1003
    ]
  }
}
"""

// Create DataFrame
val df = spark.read.json(Seq(jsonData).toDS).toDF

// Explode the array column and then filter.
val newdf = df.select($"id", explode($"batters.batter").as("batter")).filter("batter = 1001")
newdf.show()
```

// Output

```
+----+------+
|  id|batter|
+----+------+
|0001|  1001|
+----+------+
```

You can also refer to my [blog](https://medium.com/expedia-group-tech/working-with-json-in-apache-spark-1ecf553c2a8c) for "Working with JSON in Apache Spark"

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

`function array_contains should have been array followed by a value with same element type, but it's [array<array<string>>, string].; line 1 pos 45;`

This is because `brand_id` is of type `array<array<string>>` & you are passing value is of type `string`, You have to wrap your value inside `array` i.e

`array_contains(goods.brand_id, array('45c060b9-3645-49ad-86eb-65f3cd4e9081'))`

Above will work only if we pass exact number of brand_id values i.e. `array_contains(goods.brand_id, array('<should match same number of elements in brand_id>'))`

Check below code.

```
scala> df.printSchema
root
 |-- goods: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- brand_id: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- product_id: string (nullable = true)


scala> spark.sql("select * from goodsInfo").show(false)
+----------------------+
|goods                 |
+----------------------+
|[[[B100, B101], P100]]|
|[[[B200, B200], P200]]|
|[[[B300], P300]]      |
+----------------------+

scala> spark.sql("select * from goodsInfo where array_contains(goods.brand_id, array('B300'))").show(false) // Exact one element
+----------------+
|goods           |
+----------------+
|[[[B300], P300]]|
+----------------+

scala> spark.sql("select * from goodsInfo where array_contains(goods.brand_id, array('B100'))").show(false) // Passing single element from array. It will not give result.
+-----+
|goods|
+-----+
+-----+


scala> spark.sql("select * from goodsInfo where array_contains(goods.brand_id, array('B100','B101'))").show(false) // Pass complete array, It will give result.
+----------------------+
|goods                 |
+----------------------+
|[[[B100, B101], P100]]|
+----------------------+
```

Instead of `array_contains` try using `LATERAL VIEW explode` to explode nested `array` values, Check below query.

```
SELECT 
 goods
,brand_id 
FROM goodsInfo 
LATERAL VIEW explode(goods.brand_id) brands as brands 
LATERAL VIEW explode(brands) brand_id as brand_id
WHERE brand_id = '45c060b9-3645-49ad-86eb-65f3cd4e9081';
```